# Android app crash with android.app.RemoteServiceException:

Tags: android

Has anybody seen apps crashing with this exception in google play console crash logs and have any idea what it is?

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2057)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7711)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:516)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

As you can see there is no exception message present which is really unhelpful. We cannot replicate this locally and have never seen it happen.

I doubt anybody would know what it is but if you have any suggestions on getting more info it would be great.

I cannot paste the code as it is a reasonably large project and it could be anywhere. Also unfortunately it started happening a long time ago so we cannot limit it to a certain commit either.